# How to link favicon to a random css color?

Tags: javascript, php, html, random, favicon

I'm trying to make it so my favicon is the same color as the spot color on my website. The spot color on my website randomly changes between 3 colors on every refresh (using javascript). I was almost able to get my favicons to randomly change but I am not sure how to approach linking them to specific colors in my javascript instead. Check out my website here.

```
HTML & PHP:

<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="../images/favicon_<?php echo rand(1,3); ?>.ico"/>
</head

Javascript:

var colors = ['#FFCB80', '#5A53EA', '#65CE9C'];
var random_color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.tag').css('color', random_color);
   $('#nav a:hover').css('color', "black");
   $('#nav a:link').css('color', random_color);
   $('#nav a:visited').css('color', random_color);
   $('.number').css('color', random_color);

});
```

Comment: Website: http://www.khom.us

Comment: The point of a favicon is to make it easy for people to find your URL in a list.  I think you should choose a favicon carefully and use just one.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the random number generated in the php code in the javascript.

**Edit**: I visited your web and I saw you have the javascript in a different file, so you could create a js variable, in the document head for example, to store the color index, and then use the same variable name inside the js file to use it.

Also, I saw that your HTML code is printing this literally:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="../images/favicon_<php echo rand(1,3); ?>.ico">
```

Please, check it because it seems the page is not being processed by PHP.

HTML & PHP:

```
<?php
$randomIndex = rand(1,3); // From 1 to 3
?>

<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="../images/favicon_<?php echo $randomIndex; ?>.ico"/>
<script>
var random_color_index = <?php echo $randomIndex-1; ?>; // From 0 to 2
</script>
</head>
```

Javascript:

```
var colors = ['#FFCB80', '#5A53EA', '#65CE9C'];
var random_color = colors[random_color_index]; // From 0 to 2

$(document).ready(function() {

$('.tag').css('color', random_color);
$('#nav a:hover').css('color', "black");
$('#nav a:link').css('color', random_color);
$('#nav a:visited').css('color', random_color);
$('.number').css('color', random_color);
```

Answer (score 0):

With Javascript solution you can pass your `new url` and `id` of your link stylesheet to function below to update external css regularly. Please review this one:

```js
function changeHref(url, id) {
  var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    mylink = document.getElementById(id);
  if (!mylink) {
    mylink = document.createElement('link');
    mylink.id = id;
    mylink.rel = 'stylesheet';
    mylink.type = 'text/css';
  }
  mylink.href = url;
  h.appendChild(mylink);
  console.log(mylink);
}
changeHref("//yourUrl", "yourlinkId");
```